# Dividir IP en parte de host y red en c

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un programa en c para dividir una IP en las partes de host y de red, tengo el siguiente código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(){

struct in_addr addr;
uint8_t *ip={193,110,128,200};
//convierto la IP de uint8_t a uint32_t
uint32_t *ipint = (uint32_t *)ip;
addr.s_addr=ipint;

//empleo las funciones siguientes que devuelven la parte host y la parte red, respectivamente
uint32_t host = inet_lnaof(addr);
uint32_t red = inet_netof(addr);
//convierto el resultado a uint8_t
uint8_t *hostB = (uint8_t *)&host;
uint8_t *redB = (uint8_t *)&red;
//imprimo el resultado
printf("host B: %u.%u.%u.%u\n",hostB[0],hostB[1],hostB[2],hostB[3]);
printf("red B: %u.%u.%u.%u\n",redB[0], redB[1], redB[2], redB[3]);
printf("\n");

}
```

El problema es que no logro imprimir el resultado correcto.
Utilizando como ejemplo la IP del código, el resultado es:

```
 host B: 0.0.0.0
 red B: 0.0.193.0
```

El 193 es correcto, sin embargo no me imprime el resto de los números. ¿A qué podría deberse este resultado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El código que muestras da diversos *avisos*.

Si los solucionamos, cambiando ...

```
uint8_t *ip = {193,110,128,200};
```

y

```
addr.s_addr=ipint;
```

Obtenemos un código que compila sin problemas ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(){

struct in_addr addr;
uint8_t ip[] = {193,110,128,200}; // <- AQUÍ
//convierto la IP de uint8_t a uint32_t
uint32_t *ipint = (uint32_t *)ip;
addr.s_addr=*ipint; // <- AQUÍ

//empleo las funciones siguientes que devuelven la parte host y la parte red, respectivamente
uint32_t host = inet_lnaof(addr);
uint32_t red = inet_netof(addr);
//convierto el resultado a uint8_t
uint8_t *hostB = (uint8_t *)&host;
uint8_t *redB = (uint8_t *)&red;
//imprimo el resultado
printf("host B: %u.%u.%u.%u\n",hostB[0],hostB[1],hostB[2],hostB[3]);
printf("red B: %u.%u.%u.%u\n",redB[0], redB[1], redB[2], redB[3]);
printf("\n");

}
```

Y al ejecutarlo, obtenemos la siguiente salida:

> host B: 200.0.0.0
>   red B: 128.110.193.0

Comment: El problema del orden de los bytes? Excelente respuesta !

Comment: Muchas gracias! Creía que ip[] e *ip eran equivalentes.